# How to return array of JSON when AngularJs component call it by URL

Tags: json, angularjs, jakarta-ee, ejb, ng-grid

I going to use AngularJs component "ng-grid" to show the list of person on that data-grid. In "main.js" that component should read the data from an URL like this

```
$http.get('http://localhost:7001/UserPortal/test/json/JsonResualt.jsf').success(function (largeLoad)
```

and my problem is how to define it !

Actually I wrote a method to fetch data and convert it to the JSONArray like this

```
    public String toJson(){
    String query = "select * from t_person";
    JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject();

    JSONArray prsJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        ArrayList<PersonBean> persons = some code to fetch data
        for (PersonBean personBean : persons) {     
            JSONObject prsJsObj = new JSONObject();             
            prsJsObj.putOpt(String.valueOf(persons.indexOf(personBean)), personBean);
            prsJsonArray.put(prsJsObj);
        }   
        jsObj.put("prsJsonArray", prsJsonArray);
        getResponse().setContentType("application/json");
        getResponse().getWriter().write(jsObj.toString());


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I debug it, in 'prsJsonArray' I have array of JSON data and I could wite it on response object.
My question is, How could I call this method directly from URL ? Or could I do some way else to handle this issue ?!
I use J2EE and EJB and my web page is JSF

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What ?!! actually your are trying to mix two opposite architecture paradigm ! J2EE/EJB/JSF which is server side templating, and angular which is in 99% of cases used with a REST architecture. To do what you want you have to export you JAVA method via REST (using SPRING for example), and call it simply with $http in an angular APP (not in a JSF page)... I seriously advise you to not trying to mix JSF with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You got something completly wrong. You use a JSF page as a webservice, which is terrible. If you wan't to create a webservice to retrieve JSON objects, you should create a restful service with something like Spring or JAX-RS.
For Example with JAX-RS:

```
@Path("userportal/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        //Or retrieve data from DB by calling a DAO for example

        return track;

    }
}
```